# Change widget placement?

Tags: orchardcms

I have this login widget already created. It has the usual fields for username, password, a forgot password link and a login button, all inside a 200x200 box.

I am creating few content items (new content type with Body, Login widget, and couple of other parts). Each content item/page will display this login widget, but not in the same 'zone'. In some of the pages, the login widget should appear on AsideFirst, and in other pages the login widget should appear on AsideSecond. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what [widget layers](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets) are for.

Create two layers for both sets of pages (using available rules). Next, add one widget to *AsideFirst* on the *first layer* and second widget to *AsideSecond* on *second layer.*

Comment: Thanks. A separate issue. I just noticed the widget is not showing up if I change the zone to anything other than 'Content'. This works - <Place Parts_LoginWidget="Content:1"/>, anything other than 'Content' doesn't work, the widget doesn't show up on the page. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If the *Parts_LoginWidget* shape describes the content of your widget then it's perfectly ok - it should be placed in Content. The placement.info file describes the **local** zones of a given item (so eg. a Header, Footer or Content of the widget itself), not the whole site. Widgets have only those three zones. In order to place a whole widget inside a zone - use the Widgets admin pane.

Comment: I created two new layers, I have added the rule to use the right layer. One more issue, I need to add some static HTML content to "AfterMain" zone, the html is different for the two sets of pages. Is this possible? When I create a new page and add some html content to it, it all goes under "Content" zone.

Comment: You can do exactly the same as with your LoginWidget - use two HtmlWidgets for that - add one in one layer and the second in the second layer.